# A word that means a huge amount of technical emigrants

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word that means *a huge amount of technical emigrants*.

I came a cross a term I don't remember anymore; I believe it means when talents are leaving the country.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'technical immigrant'? It's not a term I've ever come across in English.

Comment: I came a cross a term that I don't remember it, I believe it means when talents are leaving the country.

Comment: With respect to people *leaving* the country, you want ***e**migrants*, not ***im**migrants*. There is no single word that designates huge amounts of just that kind of people. *Technical* is ambiguous in this context; *educated* or *skilled* or *technically skilled/educated* Will you be satisfied with a term that means "a large number of people", such as ***hordes** of skilled emigrants* or ***swarms** of skilled emigrants* or ***legions** of skilled emigrants*?

Comment: An exodus of emigrant technologists  (from the point of view of the country they are leaving).  An inlux of immigrant technologists (from the point of the country they are coming to)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might be looking for the term [brain drain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_capital_flight), which has a nice rhyme in it. According to Wikipedia,

> The term "brain drain" was coined by the Royal Society to describe the emigration of "scientists and technologists" to North America from post-war Europe. Another source indicates that this term was first used in the United Kingdom to describe the influx of Indian scientists and engineers.

Comment: The OP was asking about immigration, not emigration. Surely the article on the UK referred to the "Brain Drain from ... to the UK."

Comment: @Peter in the comments, he states *I believe it means when talents are leaving the country.* That should maybe be added to the question, though.